# Reference static method from code in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to reference a class static method to use with `call_user_func` without using strings?

Right now, the only two options I know to invoke the `register` method in an `User` class are this:

```
call_user_func([User::class, 'register']);
call_user_func(User::class . '::register');
```

Both ways require to use a string to identify the method, making code impossible to refactor.

As an example, for instance properties I'm using this workaround that works just fine:

```
class User {
    /**
     * @return static
    */
    public static function prop()
    {
       return new PropertyName();
    }
}

class PropertyName
{    
    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $name;
    }
}
```

So I could write this having autocomplete and refactoring support:

```
User::factory()
  ->where(User::prop()->email, $email)
  ->get_one()
```

Comment: AFAIK no. That's PHP for you. Classes and functions aren't first class entities. Even `::class` is sort of a hacky addon to make it _slightly_ easier.

Comment: @Javier. Your question is like `Can I achieve dynamism without using dynamism ?` Answer is NO. In PHP dynamism (or changing runnable function on the fly) is achieved by putting that function name in some string/variable.

Comment: I just found that my IDE, PhpStorm, has refactoring support when referencing static methods like `call_user_func([User::class, 'register']);`. It could work for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "Is there any way to reference a class static method to use with call_user_func without using strings?" - Yes

But im not sure this is what you want :D

```
class Foo {

    public static function bar() {
        echo "yaay \o/";
    }

}

call_user_func(function() {
    Foo::bar();
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but my goal is to get a reference to the static method that is valid for serialization, and closures aren't.